# Why does my review icon say 12 when there are no posts to review?

Tags: support, bug, status-reproduced

My SE toolbar has an orange review icon showing "12", but when I click on it, it takes me to the Review page which doesn't show any review items:

[image: screenshot of review page]

Nothing I do seems to clear the 12. (Yesterday and earlier, it was 10, and seems to have jumped to 12 for some reason today.)

Any ideas?

Comment: You might find this post on Meta Stack Exchange relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85366/dont-display-pending-edit-counter-if-youve-exhausted-your-suggested-edit-votes

Comment: There's a feature / change in the pipe that will fix this _most_ of the time. There's still a discrepancy between reviews you skipped, reviews you did, and the total number of reviews, but this _should_ soon make more sense.

Answer (score 5):

I agree it is confusing, I have the same.

My guess is that the 10 reviews are due to the site self evaluation. You have already done them, but the questions are still open to review by others.

The extra two come probably from close/reopen votes or suggested edits already reviewed by you, but not by a sufficient number of people to be actioned by the system.

So in total there are 12 reviews open, but you have already done all of them so nothing for you.

It would be better if the number would indicate the number of reviews open to the user.

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug related to the self-evaluation queue. The notification number is *supposed* to indicate the number of reviews that you (the logged-in user) can complete, but the number from the self-evaluation queue seems stubbornly stuck there even after you complete those items.

Comment: It's not only the self-evaluation queue, I saw 12 earlier today as well. It's now back to 10 since Peter Kampf, fooot and Skip Miller have reviewed close votes and low quality posts that were not reviewable by me.

Comment: Yep, mine was stuck at 12 as well, now down to 10.

Answer (score 3):

+3 years on and it's still there :(

It's not just a quality-of-life request, as the counter can show nothing and there would be stuff needing [my] attention in the queue.

[image]

Comment: "can show nothing and there would be stuff needing attention in the queue." the counter appears only if the items open for review are more than 2, as far as I can see

Comment: @Federico - clarified what I meant, thanks.

Comment: I think it was clear, but still, if the open items in the queue are strictly less than 3, the number won't appear, it is not dependent on who can review them. As others have said, it's not a bug, it's by design (that to me does not make sense, but that's another topic)

Answer (score 2):

Once you graduate from reviewing suggested edits to being able to review items in other queues, the meaning of that number changes.  It no longer represents the number of suggested edits you can review, but is a number that is vaguely related to the total number of items that could potentially be reviewed by somebody.  [Apparently, this is by design](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/the-change-to-the-taskbar-is-massively-annoying/5763#5763).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me too.

I completed reviewing the site self-evaluation as well, and my toolbar still shows them as awaiting my review.  When I click on it, the review queue is empty.

Marking it as [status-reproduced](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) so that someone can take a look at it.

Comment: This notation has happened to me on other SE's as well; after I go through a review queue the number stays up on my bar for a while.  There seems to be a delay in the system before those get cleaned out, as there are delays in the system for badges arriving ...