# 1 featured question, but no question shows up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that there is 1 featured question badge, but no questions are showing up:

[image]

I'm not sure if its related to [Why does my review icon say 12 when there are no posts to review?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/why-does-my-review-icon-say-12-when-there-are-no-posts-to-review)

Comment: have you tried to empty the browser cache? I do not see any featured question.

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to the review count in the top bar.

We cache pretty much everything possible, and featured question count is one of those things. Once in a while (although it is rare), the count goes out of sync with reality.

This generally fixes itself, and I see that it already has by the time I'm looking at the site.

Answer (score 2):

Around the time you posted this, there was an open bounty just going into its grace period. Probably the bounty was not yet awarded so the system would have identified it as "open". But since the grace period already started there was no way to participate in the bounty hunt.

The bounty was manually awarded (to me) 2 hours before Adam Lear posted. So by that time the problem had "fixed itself".

I still think there is a minor inconsistency in flagging things as featured / open for review in the top bar and the actual state of bounty / review lists.